# Looping through table and column combinations

Tags: sql, for-loop, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I need to make a script that goes through all tables, and select those columns where
name is specified.

I can find the columns where names are specified,

```
SELECT sys.columns.name AS ColumnName, tables.name AS TableName 
FROM sys.columns 
JOIN sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
                AND sys.columns.name LIKE 'name'
```

but how do in SQL loop through each row of the select statement and exectute an update command on the table `TableName` and and column  `ColumnName`, and update the content to something like
'Anon'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just supposed your searching exact name and don't use Wild cards like `%,?,_`. You can use the below query:

```
declare @query varchar(max), @val varchar(100);

set @val ='L';

SELECT @query = COALESCE(@query+ '; ','')+ 'update '+  s.name +'.' + t.name +' set '+ sys.columns.name +' = '''+ @val +''''
FROM sys.columns 
JOIN sys.tables t ON sys.columns.object_id = t.object_id
                AND sys.columns.name LIKE '%Name%'
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id


select @query
 
 exec (@query)
```

Comment: The select query seems a bit different in yours?

Comment: Yeah, I added a schemas table into the query also because a table can be in another schema. @IamnotFat